# Unable to connect to any servers Cassandra2

Tags: cassandra-2.0, datastax-enterprise, cqlsh

Using Datastax 4.8.11 Cassandra 2.1.17 on Ubuntu 14.04
Everything was working fine but suddenly not. cqlsh unable to connect to server.
I am successfully starting dse and datastax-agent and they are running fine, including cassandra.

```
@ubuntu:~$ cqlsh
    Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'192.168.254.143': error(113, "Tried connecting to [('192.168.254.143', 9042)]. Last error: No route to host")})
```

Tried below but did not help

```
$ sudo service netwrok-manager restart
```

I think this has to do with DHCP - my VM IP is changing and does not match the IP in Cassandra config (how to make static IP?). I tried cqlsh providing it new IP : cqlsh 192.168.254.146 9160. I tried both ports 9160 (rpc_port) and 9042 (native_transport_port) both don't work (which one to use?). But the error msg is different now "Connection refused" (instead of no route to host).

Thanks

Comment: Updated .yaml rpc_address and listen_address to localhost, restarted Cassandra (DSE/datastax-agent). Now cqlsh tried to go to 127.0.0.1/9042 - but again "Connection refused"

Answer (score 3):

In your cassandra.yaml file in the places where you specify the ip address:
'listen_address', rpc_address' and 'seeds' you do not have to specify the port.
Just enter the ip address.

Also make sure all the ports required by cassandra are open
Run the following command on terminal

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 9042 -j ACCEPT
```

do this for the following ports: 9042,7000,7001,7199,9042,9160

Comment: Thank you for this. Just to confirm it worked by opening only 9042 and 9160 in our case.